# TypeError when creating PersonGroup in Face API

Tags: python, face

I am getting this error while running the code the response is having a keyword json which is not readable.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tomst\Documents\Pycharm_Projects\Github_FaceRog\person_group.py", line 15, in <module>
    res = CF.person_group.create("ttpersons")
  File "C:\Users\tomst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cognitive_face\person_group.py", line 32, in create
    return util.request('PUT', url, json=json)
  File "C:\Users\tomst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cognitive_face\util.py", line 92, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\tomst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
```

Code:

```
import sys
import cognitive_face as CF




Key = '4d443a3c323043868219d5dc2e064d04'
CF.Key.set(Key)

BASE_URL = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0'  
CF.BaseUrl.set(BASE_URL)


res = CF.person_group.create("ttpersons")
```